# Generate list from JavaScript object

Tags: javascript

This is my data:

```
var tabledata = {
0: {Name: "Server1", PRPName: "NO_PRP", OperatingSystem: "Linux", SLA: "SILVER", Environment: "Accept"}
1: {Name: "Server2", PRPName: "services", OperatingSystem: "Linux", SLA: "SILVER", Environment:"Accept"}
2: {Name: "Server3", PRPName: "NO_PRP", OperatingSystem: "Windows", SLA: "GOLD", Environment: "Accept"}
3: {Name: "Server4", PRPName: "services", OperatingSystem: "Linux", SLA: "GOLD", Environment: "Accept"}
4: {Name: "Server5", PRPName: "NO_PRP", OperatingSystem: "Windows", SLA: "GOLD", Environment: "Accept"}
5: {Name: "Server6", PRPName: "sql", OperatingSystem: "Windows", SLA: "GOLD", Environment: "Accept"}
6: {Name: "Server7", PRPName: "services", OperatingSystem: "Linux", SLA: "GOLD", Environment: "Production"}
7: {Name: "Server8", PRPName: "NO_PRP", OperatingSystem: "Windows", SLA: "GOLD", Environment: "Production"}
8: {Name: "Server9", PRPName: "sql", OperatingSystem: "Windows", SLA: "GOLD", Environment: "Production"}
```

And i need to create a list from Name: like this.

```
servernames = ["Server1","Server2","Server3","Server4","Server5","Server6","Server7","Server8"]
```

Comment: There is no JSON here.

Comment: You should be having an array, instead of an element, and even if you want to have an element then your field names are invalid. Once you fix your JSON, you can use the `map` function and return the names of the elements in that list.

Comment: Is this something you need? `const servernames = Object.values(tabledata).map(({ Name }) => Name)`

Comment: Objects with keys 0 to 8 desire to be arrays. `Object.values(tabledata).map(({ Name }) => Name);`.

Comment: Your snippet contains JavaScript syntax errors -- I am assuming you are constructing an array referred to with `tabledata`, but you need to separate element definition with commas, and you are missing a closing curly bracket.

Comment: Thx for the help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by the others, you have a JavaScript object (a map between numbers and objects representing server data), and not a JSON.

To get the server names from this object, you can use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to first extract the object's property values with server information and then [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get only the server name, generating an array with those:

```js
var tabledata = {
  0: {Name: "Server1", PRPName: "NO_PRP", OperatingSystem: "Linux", SLA: "SILVER", Environment: "Accept"},
  1: {Name: "Server2", PRPName: "services", OperatingSystem: "Linux", SLA: "SILVER", Environment:"Accept"},
  2: {Name: "Server3", PRPName: "NO_PRP", OperatingSystem: "Windows", SLA: "GOLD", Environment: "Accept"},
  3: {Name: "Server4", PRPName: "services", OperatingSystem: "Linux", SLA: "GOLD", Environment: "Accept"},
  4: {Name: "Server5", PRPName: "NO_PRP", OperatingSystem: "Windows", SLA: "GOLD", Environment: "Accept"},
  5: {Name: "Server6", PRPName: "sql", OperatingSystem: "Windows", SLA: "GOLD", Environment: "Accept"},
  6: {Name: "Server7", PRPName: "services", OperatingSystem: "Linux", SLA: "GOLD", Environment: "Production"},
  7: {Name: "Server8", PRPName: "NO_PRP", OperatingSystem: "Windows", SLA: "GOLD", Environment: "Production"},
  8: {Name: "Server9", PRPName: "sql", OperatingSystem: "Windows", SLA: "GOLD", Environment: "Production"}
};
var servernames = Object.values(tabledata).map((server) => server.Name);

console.log(servernames);
```

Comment: `var servernames = Object.values(tabledata).map(server => server.Name);`    get rid of the parenthesis around the args inside map function to make it even more shorter

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON:

```
var tabledata = {
"0": {Name: "Server1", PRPName: "NO_PRP", OperatingSystem: "Linux", SLA: "SILVER", Environment: "Accept"},
"1": {Name: "Server2", PRPName: "services", OperatingSystem: "Linux", SLA: "SILVER", Environment:"Accept"},
"2": {Name: "Server3", PRPName: "NO_PRP", OperatingSystem: "Windows", SLA: "GOLD", Environment: "Accept"},
"3": {Name: "Server4", PRPName: "services", OperatingSystem: "Linux", SLA: "GOLD", Environment: "Accept"},
"4": {Name: "Server5", PRPName: "NO_PRP", OperatingSystem: "Windows", SLA: "GOLD", Environment: "Accept"},
"5": {Name: "Server6", PRPName: "sql", OperatingSystem: "Windows", SLA: "GOLD", Environment: "Accept"},
"6": {Name: "Server7", PRPName: "services", OperatingSystem: "Linux", SLA: "GOLD", Environment: "Production"},
"7": {Name: "Server8", PRPName: "NO_PRP", OperatingSystem: "Windows", SLA: "GOLD", Environment: "Production"},
"8": {Name: "Server9", PRPName: "sql", OperatingSystem: "Windows", SLA: "GOLD", Environment: "Production"}
};
```

You could use `Object.values` to get an array of values of your tabledata object and then apply `Array.prototype.map` to transform the values to server names like so:

```js
const serverNames = Object.values(tabledata).map((server) => server.Name);
console.log(serverNames);
```

It will print:

```js
["Server1", "Server2", "Server3", "Server4", "Server5", "Server6", "Server7", "Server8", "Server9"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```js
var tabledata = {
0: {Name: "Server1", PRPName: "NO_PRP", OperatingSystem: "Linux", SLA: "SILVER", Environment: "Accept"},
1: {Name: "Server2", PRPName: "services", OperatingSystem: "Linux", SLA: "SILVER", Environment:"Accept"},
2: {Name: "Server3", PRPName: "NO_PRP", OperatingSystem: "Windows", SLA: "GOLD", Environment: "Accept"},
3: {Name: "Server4", PRPName: "services", OperatingSystem: "Linux", SLA: "GOLD", Environment: "Accept"},
4: {Name: "Server5", PRPName: "NO_PRP", OperatingSystem: "Windows", SLA: "GOLD", Environment: "Accept"},
5: {Name: "Server6", PRPName: "sql", OperatingSystem: "Windows", SLA: "GOLD", Environment: "Accept"},
6: {Name: "Server7", PRPName: "services", OperatingSystem: "Linux", SLA: "GOLD", Environment: "Production"},
7: {Name: "Server8", PRPName: "NO_PRP", OperatingSystem: "Windows", SLA: "GOLD", Environment: "Production"},
8: {Name: "Server9", PRPName: "sql", OperatingSystem: "Windows", SLA: "GOLD", Environment: "Production"}
}

const result = Object.keys(tabledata).map(el => tabledata[el].Name)
console.log(result)
```